# How to call methods from inside of a hash map (something to do with the :: operator?)

Tags: java, pointers, lambda, hashmap

So I've seen plenty of threads similar to this but I'm failing to understand so I'd like some help in my specific case. I've seen how to do this before java 8, create an interface with an undefined method and implement it inside of the HashMap, and that method made sense to me but I'd like to learn the new way. I only semi understand lambda operators and the :: operator but from what I can tell they're exactly what I need, I just don't get the syntax. Here's the pseudo code I'd like you to explain how to do:

```
public void doStuffA(String s) {some code A}
public void doStuffB(String s) {some code B}
public void doStuffC(String s) {some code C}

HashMap<String, MethodPointer> hmap = new HashMap<String, MethodPointer>();
hmap.put("Canada", doStuffA(String s));
hmap.put("futon", doStuffB(String s));
hmap.put("Peter", doStuffC(String s));

String str = "pass in this string";
void runStuff(String s) = hmap.get("Peter");
runStuff(str);
```

Hopefully you understand well enough what I'm trying to do here. I haven't put any of my actual code in here for fear of being told my entire program is stupid and I shouldn't write it, but the situation is similar. I have some number of methods, in this case 3, and each of them takes in a string. In the HashMap, every method is mapped to some string, in my example I used random words. I want to be able to get whatever function is being stored at a location and run it with the parameter "stuff". No matter what function I end up calling from the HashMap, I will pass the string stuff into it and run it. Write some code for me, maybe explain it, if I never end up understanding I'll just do it the java 7 and below method. I'd like to be able to do this all without creating any new classes or interfaces but the old method forces me to I think.

Comment: You might be looking for a `Consumer` mostly, but not really clear by the code in question. You should try to prototype the map as `Map<String, Consumer<String>>`.

Comment: @AdamRutledge It is not clear what exactly should be explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` shows a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The code you want would look something like this:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
...

class SomeClass {

  public void doStuffA(String s) {some code A}
  public void doStuffB(String s) {some code B}
  public void doStuffC(String s) {some code C}

  public void anotherMethod() {
    HashMap<String, Consumer<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
    hmap.put("Canada", this::doStuffA);
    hmap.put("futon", this::doStuffB);
    hmap.put("Peter", this::doStuffC);

    String str = "pass in this string";
    Consumer<String> runStuff = hmap.get("Peter");
    runStuff.accept(str);
  }
}
```

An explanation of how that code works:

The `this::doStuffA` above is a method reference to the `doStuffA` method that `this` has. If there is a different object called `obj` that has a method called `doStuffA`, you could just replace `this::doStuffA` with `obj::doStuffA`. If `doStuffA` is a static method, you can say `ClassThatDoStuffAIsIn::doStuffA`.

The [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface looks something like this:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
  void accept(T t);
}
```

It is what is known as a [**functional interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6). Functional interfaces are interfaces with a single abstract method. In this case, that method is accept.

Method references and lambda expressions are really just syntactic sugar. Java looks at the signature of your method (`doStuffA`) and the signature of the abstract method in the functional interface, and if it matches, it basically creates an object that overrides that abstract method by calling your method.

A method reference such as `Consumer<String> c = this::doStuff` or an equivalent lambda expression such as `Consumer<String> c = (s) -> doStuff(c);` really means something like this:

```
class ConsumerImpl implements Consumer<String> {
  @Override //This annotation isn't actually added, but it's just for clarity
  public void accept(String str) {
    this.doStuffA(str);
  }
}
...
Consumer<String> c = new ConsumerImpl();
```

or with an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
Consumer<String> c = new Consumer<>() {
  @Override //This annotation isn't actually added, but it's just for clarity
  public void accept(String str) {
    this.doStuffA(str);
  }
};
```

This isn't actually what happens - the JVM treats such objects specially and uses an opcode called [`invokedynamic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html#invokedynamic), but that's probably beyond the scope of this answer. For all intents and purposes, the above code is what a method reference expands to.

So you cannot just call these methods directly, like this:

```
Consumer<String> runStuff = hmap.get("Peter");
runStuff(str); //This is an error because there is no method called runStuff
```

Therefore, you have to use the `accept` method on the `Consumer` interface to actually use the `doStuffA` method.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, you don't have to use the `Consumer` interface. You can make your own interface, named whatever you want, as long as it only has 1 abstract method (which you can also name whatever you want). This would also work:

```
public interface MyBeautifulFunctionalInterface {
  void doStuffWithAString(String s);
}

and then

public static void main(String[] argh) {
  MyBeautifulFunctionalInterface runStuff = this::doStuffA;
  runStuff.doStuffWithAString("blah");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that my method was completely incorrect, as I stated it's just pseudocode. I wasn't trying to ask "make this method work for me" but more "imagine in your head that this method works, how would you do it with the :: operator that I don't understand." Which you did anyway, this solution works and I think I understand everything now. Thanks.